# What is the use of Stylesheet in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am building an android application using react-native.

part of my JSX includes,

```
<Text style={{ color: "red" }}> Styled using style prop !! </Text>
<Text style={styles.colorRed}> Styled uisng StyleSheet !!</Text>
```

and,

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  colorRed: {
    color: "red"
  }
})
```

The `Text` component seems to render same style(at least on android platform),

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style) suggests to use `StyleSheet` module. **My question is, when should I use `StyleSheet` module?**

Comment: I answered for a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58039898/7364894

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactNative inline style vs Stylesheet.create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508575/reactnative-inline-style-vs-stylesheet-create)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use StyleSheet over inline styles.

**Benfits**

- By moving styles away from the render function, you're making the
  code easier to understand.
- Naming the styles is a good way to add meaning to the low level
  components in the render function.
- The stylesheet is sent only once over the bridge unlike normal style
  object inside render().

However you can use the style property to add the styles inline. However, this is not the best practice because it can be hard to read the code.One reason you might want to not to use in-line stylesheets is to reduce the amount of duplication in the code.

**First** one is **inline** styling.

**Example**

```
<Text style={{ color: "red" }}> Styled using style prop !! </Text>
```

**Second** one is using **StyleSheet,** you create a style object and refer to each style individually. This brings the separation of styles from the render method and helps you organize the code.

**Example**

```
    <Text style={styles.colorRed}> Styled uisng StyleSheet !!</Text>
    // initialize stylesheet
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      colorRed: {
        color: "red"
      }
})
```

***When should use inline styles*** like if you have base stylesheet and you have various component with same style but with one or two properties change then you can use inline style

**Example**

```
    <Text style={[CommonStyles.textLightGrey, { alignSelf: 'flex-end' }]} >Balance</Text>
    <Text style={[CommonStyles.textLightGrey, { alignSelf: 'center' }]} >Balance</Text>
// It is my common or base stylesheet
export default StyleSheet.create({
       textLightGrey: {
        fontSize: 12,
        color: COLORS.lightgrey
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should prefer Stylesheet over inline style.
When you style in Stylesheet, you get corresponding errors on your Emulator/Device Directly, So you'll know your errors(if any), while your code might mess up in inline styling!